# Showing a list of selected/related categories to entry

Tags: categories, relatedto, products

I have a `suitability` category field in my product type that allows the content writer to select which categories this product is associated with.

But my issue is that on the product page I need to show a full list of these 'suitability' categories with a "yes" or "no" next to them indicating which categories are appropriate.

So I am getting the 'suitability' category group:

```
{% set suitability = craft.categories.group('suitability').all() %}
```

Then I am simply looping over this list, but I'm unsure how to format my if statement to dictate if this category needs a "yes" or a "no". I know it's probably something to do with the `.relatedTo()` parameter but I'm not quite sure on the formatting.

```
{% for category in suitability %}
    <dt class="data-list__item data-list__item--title">{{ category.title }}</dt>
    <dd class="data-list__item data-list__item--value">
        {% if product.relatedTo(category) %}Yes{% else %}No{% endif %}
    </dd>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indigo Viking's code will achieve what you want, but if you want a simpler solution (possibly a bit more performant since there's no second `for` loop), you could do this instead:

```
{% set suitability = craft.categories.group('suitability').all() %}

{% for category in suitability %}
    <dt class="data-list__item data-list__item--title">
        {{ category.title }}
    </dt>
    <dd class="data-list__item data-list__item--value">
        {% if category.id in product.suitability.ids() %}
            Yes
        {% else %}
            No
        {% endif %}
    </dd>
{% endfor %}
```

The way this works is `product.suitability.ids()` returns an array of the element ids of the categories selected in your `suitability` field. Then you just check if the current category's id is in that array.

Fast, simple, and easy!

Comment: Lovely stuff, I knew there was a really simple way of comparing items. Cheers, Jalen.

Answer (score 2):

```
{% set suitability = craft.categories.group('suitability').all() %}

{% for category in suitability %}
    <dt class="data-list__item data-list__item--title">
        {{ category.title }}
    </dt>
    <dd class="data-list__item data-list__item--value">
        {% for selectedCategory in product.suitability.all() %}
            {% if selectedCategory.slug == category.slug %}
                Yes
            {% else %}
                No
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </dd>
{% endfor %}
```

You'll want to loop over the list of selected categories in your product's category field (`product.suitability`) and then check the if the slug of each selected category is the same as the current slug in your main `for` loop.

Comment: This is kind of working. It's only saying "yes" by the first suitability category I've selected though.

Comment: Missed the loop for the field itself. updating answer.